# Text is not centered in div?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

So I'm kind of a begginner and I just encountered a problem that I don't know how to solve.

Here is the code:

https://jsfiddle.net/upwaqyek/

```
.parent{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    border: #000000 2px solid;
    justify-content: center;
}

.parent div {
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: rgba(197, 197, 197, 0.788);
    border: #000000 solid 2px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    transition-duration: 3s;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

I can't center the text. I think it has to do with the width and height but it really doesn't move at all. The text just stays static there at the bottom of the div and doesn't do anything when I change the div height.

I want the text to be in the center of the div, both horizontally and vertically.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just add this two properties to your `.parent div`. Of-course there are lots of ways to do this, but I'm writing answer base on your existing code.

```
.parent div {
   // your others styles
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
}
```

```css
.parent{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    border: #000000 2px solid;
    justify-content: center;
}

.parent div {
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: rgba(197, 197, 197, 0.788);
    border: #000000 solid 2px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    transition-duration: 3s;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}



.parent div:hover {
   background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="parent">
    <a>    
      <div><h2>Text</h2></div>
    </a>    
    <div><h2>Text</h2></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That worked really good. But I have one more question. What if I wanted to add a new row, like another text below the h2? Flex forces everything to stay in one row. Is there something that can be done?

Comment: @Dude1986 yeah, then add `flex-direction: column` - it positions the items in vertical order.

Comment: For more about flexbox, you should check this https://web.dev/learn/css/flexbox/

Answer (score -1):

You can center the text by making the container div a flexbox:

```
.parent div {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center; /*center horizontally */
    align-items: center; /* center vertically */
}
```

---

Your text is pushed down because `h2` tags have a default not 0 margin (The margin varies between browsers).
It's not necessary, but I would recommend setting the margin value for header tags to 0.

```
h1, h2, h3, ... {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

for the targeted `div`, add `display: flex;` to it, then to center its content **horizontally**, add `justify-content: center;` and to center its content **vertically** add `align-items: center;`

```css
.parent{

    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    border: #000000 2px solid;
    justify-content: center;

}

.parent div {

    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: rgba(197, 197, 197, 0.788);
    border: #000000 solid 2px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    transition-duration: 3s;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}



.parent div:hover {
   background-color: white;
}
```

```html
 <div class="parent">
    <a>    
    <div>
        <h2>Text</h2>
    </div>
</a>    
    <div>
        <h2>Text</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```